# Can I disable the text on password field of EditText?

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

In Android, while entering password the text is displayed. Is there any way to hide the text programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the inputType to password. Either in the xml (as an attribute of your EditText):

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

or in your program:

```
yourETView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your XML that holds the input field use the following:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Answer (score 2):

it's depend on the real device. means In device whatever the user use the devices have 1 one option was available in the setting for hide/show the text while typing text in password field so no need to worry about it, for accept text as password you can set the input type of edittext like this way

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

in xml layout file